# Awk Not ignoring white spaces

Tags: perl, awk

My input file is in this format

```
         input
         input
         output
         super
         krish
```

that is every line starts with white space and have something after whitespaces.

Now when i try "awk '{print $1}' input" in unix it is printing in the below format

```
$ awk '{print $1}' input
input
input
output
super
krish
```

But the problem is when I try

```
awk '{if(\$1 == input) print \$1;}' <file>
```

in **system** or by using **backticks** it is not printing the output, neither it is showing any error

Can anyone help me in this??

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please add your sample Input and output in code tags. Also be more clear what you are trying to achieve here in your post.

Comment: you need to quote the string.. I think what you are looking for is `awk '$1=="input"{print $1}'` but not sure.. also, if you are using `perl` already, why do you need `awk`?

Comment: What does `awk '{if(\$1 == input) print \$1;}' <file>

in system or by using backticks` mean? Show a [mcve] (note - "Complete") of the problem as right now you're getting answers based on what you've shown us but what you **haven't** shown us yet is the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to print those lines which have `input` string in their first field then following will help you.

```
awk '$1=="input"'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
     input
     input
```

In case you don't want to have spaces and print those lines whose first field is `input` then following may help you.

```
awk '$1=="input"{$1=$1;print}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
input
input
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your initial code is that you wrote `input` without any quotes. This actually implies that `input` is a variable which is defaultly assigned as an empty string in case of string operations or as the number zero in case of numeric operations.

```
awk '{if($1 == input) print $1;}' <file>
```

is therefore equivalent to (in case of string comparisons)

```
awk '{if($1 == "") print $1;}' <file>
```

So the correct answer would be any of the following :

```
awk '{if ($1 == "input") print $1 }' <file>
awk '($1 == "input"){print $1}'      <file>
awk '$1~/^input$/{print $1}'         <file>
```

If your file only has a single column, and you want to keep the original spacing:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "input") print}'        <file>
awk '($1 == "input")'                   <file>
awk '$1~/^input$/'                      <file>
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*input[[:blank:]]*$/' <file>
```

**note:** the regex operation `/.../` does not require quotes. So `/input/` works.

**note:** escaping the `$` sign using `\$` does not work. The `\` is assumed to be the line-break character and is expected to be the last character on the line. So the original code breaks.